# Port 3306 stopped working

Tags: port

I can ping to mysql server but can not telnet to 3306 port.

```
# ping 10.10.10.99
PING 10.10.10.99 (10.10.10.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.99: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.128 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.99: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.099 ms

--- 10.10.10.99 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.099/0.113/0.128/0.018 ms

# telnet 10.10.10.99 3306
Trying 10.10.10.99...
telnet: connect to address 10.10.10.99: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

On the MySQL server:
# netstat -na | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN
```

Firewall is disabled on mysql server. This was working as expected. But I did 2 changes on mysql server. Reinstalled mysql and installed a third party software recently. How do I connect to mysql server on port 3306?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you've managed to tell MySQL to only bind to 127.0.0.1. Edit `/etc/my.cnf` and change the [`bind-address` option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address), or remove it altogether.

Comment: Depending on the distribution that is usually the default setup.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is displayed in your netstat output. Mysql is bound to the loopback address.

Check your /etc/mysql/my.cnf (if you are running Debian, or ubuntu) and change the bind-address from 
bind-address = 127.0.0.1 to bind-address = 10.10.10.99

Also I would make sure you have proper security and firewall rules setup to protect your mysql server.

Comment: Changing to bind to 10.10.10.99 is a bad idea, unless you're also binding it to 127.0.0.1; better to bind to 0.0.0.0, in case he accesses the MySQL server directly from the server.

Comment: The reason I said to bind to the 10.10.10.99 address is so it's a specified address, if you have multiple IP's this would expose it to other networks and interfaces that may not be as protected.